# How do I beat the Joker in Arkham city?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I'm stuck at the Steel Mill in Joker's Funland trying to beat the Joker, inmates and Titans.  I can't figure out how to beat the Titans.  I'm playing the Xbox 360. How do I beat them?

Answer (score 0):

You beat the titans in the same way you beat them earlier- you ultra stun them (B, B, B) then punch them several times to ride them. If there are no henchmen left, this will takedown the titan instead.

The only difference is that there are more and better armed henchmen than in the earlier fights. You'll need to defeat some of them or get extremely lucky to ultra stun a titan. If you do decide to focus on the henchmen (don't worry about Joker, he's invincible in this fight), keep an eye on the titan, keep your distance and dodge if it charges you.